# How to cancel an async connect method after X seconds in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, mqttnet

I am creating a mqtt client in C# with the libray MQTTNet.
I wan't my client to connect to a broker and stop after 1 second if doesn't succeed.
Here is the function I made below.

```
private async Task TryConnect(MqttClientOptions options)
{
     CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
     mqttClient!.ConnectAsync(options, tokenSource.Token);
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

The method is working but it gives me a warning when I call the method `ConnectAsync` because I am not using an await operator before the call. And if I use the await operator the method will continue until it will raise an error.

Is there a way to do this without warnings ? Because even if it is working I have the feeling that this is not the better way to do it and that there is a cleaner way.

Thank you for your help,

Emmanuel

Comment: The `MqttClientOptions` has a property `KeepAlivePeriod` that as deault is 15 seconds, set this property to 1 second it should work ex `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);`

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-6.0):

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
await mqttClient!.ConnectAsync(options, tokenSource.Token);
```

An alternative would be to store the task from `connectAsync` and await if after the cancel call.

Note that in either case you are not guaranteed that the connection will actually cancel, it entirely depends on the `ConnectAsync`-implementation. In some cases it might be approrpiate to use [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-6.0) to await either the connection, or a Task.Delay, i.e. you do no longer care about the connection after the timeout. You should probably also catch `OperationCancelledException`, since that is the standard method to communicate that the operation actually was cancelled.

Comment: Perfect the use of Task.WhenAny works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a timeout for a cancellation token:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

If you're cancelling it like this you will need to catch a `TaskCanceledException`, but you can ignore the cancellation if you want.

```
private async Task TryConnect(MqttClientOptions options)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    try
    {
        mqttClient!.ConnectAsync(options, tokenSource.Token);
    }

    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could return a `bool` to indicate whether the connection was successful:

```
private async Task<bool> TryConnect(MqttClientOptions options)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    try
    {
        mqttClient!.ConnectAsync(options, tokenSource.Token);
    }

    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```